# clearing many MATLAB functions in one single file

Tags: matlab

I have many small functions in matlab, is it possible to put them all in one file so my work will look clearer?

i tried writing a small script and then adding the functions but is didn't work

any idea on how do do it?

Comment: Could you share your script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *not* possible to have several functions in one file, because the function is accessed via the file name. That is why a function has to have the same name as the file name.

If you only access the "small" functions inside one other function, then you can put the small functions in the file of the other function, but then they are only accessible to this one function. This is called *local functions* in MATLAB. For example you have a file `test.m` with:

```
function x=test(y,z)
    x = add(y,z)
end

function a=add(b,c)
    a = b + c;
end
```

You can then only use `add` inside `test`, but you can use `test` just as usual.

What I usually do is put functions in subfolders. This helps you keep your path clean without any limitations. This also allows you to capsule your software better. The only thing you have to do is add the folder to your path with

```
addpath('subfolder');
```

Comment: thats sad, cant understand why they did it that way, but ok ty

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function file, you can add other functions in that file.

If you have a script, you cannot add functions to it.

Note that if you put a function in a file, you cannot access the functions directly from outside your 'main' function scope.

---

In general I would recommend the use of folders, or proper file names to organize your functions, not stacking many of them in one file.

**Extra**

If your functions are really small and trivial, you could write a script with the declaration of anonymous functions for easy reuse. However this is probably not what you want.